# Stuck while using Facebook's Oauth with Python Flask as a backend service

Tags: facebook, flask, oauth-2.0

I'm currently building out an API in Python Flask and am working on my authentication layer. Everything seems to be working aside from my request to retrieve an access token from Facebook's API.

I'm redirecting to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize after my own authorize endpoint is hit and the response is HTML. On browser, this obviously works, but since my intention is to use this API as the backend of an IOS app, I'm looking for an endpoint that returns the url, rather than the html, of the facebook login. Is there another endpoint I should be using?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Have you read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow ?

Comment: Also if you are going to use it on iOS I'm pretty sure you need to use the SDK https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios

Comment: If my API is a completely separate service, I wouldn't still need the SDK right?

Comment: 8.2 on https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ say that Native iOS and Android apps have to use the official SDKs for Login.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, nevermind, I realized that I was redirecting my API to the authorization URL when I should be returning the URL so that the user on the client side can then be redirected there.